# IBM Watson-IOT Platform Dashboard Public URL

Tags: raspberry-pi, watson-iot

I have sensors connected to a Raspberry Pi and using Node-Red on the Pi, I have them connected to IBM Watson-IOT. I created a board with 2 cards showing nice gauges. I want to 'share' this with a 'public' url - does anyone know how to easily do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not currently a way to share the boards and cards you create within the Watson IoT platform dashboard to a public url - those are only viewable by users who have access to view your IoT dashboard.

You could possibly create your own application to visualize the data and publish that externally, but there is not a way to open your dashboard configured cards for public viewing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I went and created the node-red iot boiler plate app and added the node-red dashboard node to it and was able to get it up and running that way. So my ui showing the gauges is now available on my own url....

Comment: Glad to hear you have it working! Thanks for the update.

Answer (score 0):

Currently that can't be done....but you can use freeboard for a similar effect

Comment: Can you add a link/further reference to "freeboard"?

Comment: the official page is https://freeboard.io/ and a link pentru setup https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-kA0whFEMNE

Answer (score 0):

As answered above this is currently not possible but I can highly recommend using NodeRED and the new dash-boarding function for this...(comes also as a ready to use boilerplate in IBM Bluemix)

[Tutorial](http://developers.sensetecnic.com/article/a-node-red-dashboard-using-node-red-dashboard/)
[Source](https://github.com/node-red/node-red-dashboard)